# jquery ajax success php while

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

why do everytime i success ajax request, the output will execute for each of my php while? i just want one of them which has uniq **id_cart** execute.

HTML :

```
<ul>
<?php while { ?>
    <li class="changeweight">
        <form>
            <select name="changeq" class="<?php echo $datacart['id_cart']; ?>">
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

AJax :

```
$("select[name=changeq]").change(function() {
    var selectq = $(this).val();
    var selectidcart = $(this).attr("class");
        $.ajax({
            context  : this,
            type     : "GET",
            url      : "ajax/changequantity.php",
            dataType : "json",
            data     : {idcart : selectidcart, q : selectq},
            success  : function(changeq) {
                $("li.changeweight").hide().html(changeq.totalweight).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
    });
```

changequantity.php :

```
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];
$idcart = $_GET['idcart'];
     mysqli_query($connect,"UPDATE cart SET quantity = '$q' WHERE id_cart = '$idcart'");

     $cart = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id_cart = '$idcart'");
        $datacart = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cart);

        $product = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM product WHERE id_product = '$datacart[id_product]'");
            $dataproduct = mysqli_fetch_assoc($product);

$totalweight = $datacart['quantity'] * $dataproduct['weight'];

echo json_encode(array("totalweight" => $totalweight));
?>
```

everything works good, the data store on my database, but the problem was
ajax success will do for every php while li.changeweight.

what's wrong here?

thanks you so much.

Comment: how many forms and select you want so you have kept it in while

Comment: a lot of while, that form works for changing stock of product that people buy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello try to work with current object and get it's parents

```
$("select[name=changeq]").change(function() {
    var self = this;
    var selectq = $(this).val();
    var selectidcart = $(this).attr("class");
        $.ajax({
            context  : this,
            type     : "GET",
            url      : "ajax/changequantity.php",
            dataType : "json",
            data     : {idcart : selectidcart, q : selectq},
            success  : function(changeq) {
                $(self).parent().parent().hide().html(changeq.totalweight).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks you so much dyachenko! u save my life tonight!